# how to connect to a network from getScanResults()

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to connect to a wifi hot spot with the strongest signal from the result of WifiManager.getScanResults(). but somehow i cannot enable my device accessing the network even the `boolean b` shows true.

```
  wc.SSID = "\".xxxxx\"";//result from the getScanResults()
            wc.preSharedKey  = "\"abcdefg111\"";
            wc.hiddenSSID = true;
            wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        
            wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
            Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
            boolean b=false;
            b= wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);        
            Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );
```